# How to see all columns of of DuckDb relation while printing it using show command

Tags: python-3.x, duckdb

I have created a relation object using `duckdb.sql()` command. While showing it on my jupyter notebook, it doesn't show all columns. show method defines parameter for showing `max_rows`, but not columns. Is there any way i can see all columns ? [image]

I have been through the Duckdb documentation, but couldn't find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is `max_width` option to control number of characters to show for `show` method, you can set this parameter as large as you want (e.g. `max_width=10000`). Usually, you will set `max_width` as large as possible to show all of the columns.

Be aware that if your table/dataframe have too many columns or your column has too much data inside (e.g. column contains text from a book), you might have trouble visualizing in jupyter notebook.

Reference: http://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/reference/#duckdb.DuckDBPyRelation.show (they don't explain each parameter in detail but you can guess what the parameter is about)

Comment: the value provided is the number of characters and not the number or columns

Comment: Thank @howaryoo for the clarity, I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all columns for doing ad-hoc analysis, try using `.mode line` this will output each column on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Yooakim answer, for the duckdb tool the `.mode box` is the right answer to show all columns and rows in a similar fashion instead of the default `.mode duckbox`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following code

```
duckdb.sql("select * from table").show(max_width=250)
```

Adjust the max width according to your liking.